# Is it possible to transfer water from a water bottle using condensation?

Tags: water, condensation

So currently I am travelling in a tropical country. I took my water bottle from the fridge and left it on the table, after a few hours it created a pool of water.

Is this water from the outside air or from the water bottle 'sweating'?

Comment: Your title is entirely different from the question in the body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the water vapour present in the air around the bottle, that condenses on the cool surface of the water bottle,not from the water bottle itself.